# нужно включать объект когда я начинаю пальцем перемещать другой объект

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

суть вот в чем: когда я начинаю двигать объект пальцем по экрану, появляется корзина, и если объект соприкасается с этой корзиной, то они оба ставятся на false.
это код который я использую для перемещения объекта пальцем по экрану:

```
  void moveObject()
   {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
     

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            moveobject = true;
           
       transform.position =
             new Vector3(

               transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speed,
              transform.position.y,
           transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speed);
           
        }
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
          moveobject = false;
        }

    }
  
}
```

а это код который я использую для включения/выключения корзины(скрипт прикреплен на пустой объект в Unity):

```
 void Update()
{
    Basket();
}

void Basket()
{
    if (moveObject.moveobject)
    {
        destroyObject.Basket.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        destroyObject.Basket.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

когда начинаю двигать объект, корзина не появляется...

и вот еще что: если я писал destroyObject.Basket.SetActive(true); в скрипте, который отвечает за перемещение объекта, то объект просто не хотел двигаться...

Comment: А не проще ли в первом скрипте перед условием приписать if(touch.phase==TouchPhase.Begin) Basket.SetActive(true); где Basket - публичная переменная, в которую вы укажите вашу корзину. Это не может никак влиять на движение объекта, так как он двигается в другом условии.

Comment: типа так?:  if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                destroyObject.Basket.SetActive(true);
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
              {
                      ....
                         }}
все равно не помогает - объект двигаться не хочет... скрипт который отвечает за выключение объекта при соприкосновении с коллайдером корзины висит на корзине, если этот скрипт перенести на какой-то другой объект, то все работает( когда двигаю объект корзина появляется, но уже об корзину объект не уничтожается)

Comment: P.S.: сделал все как Вы сказали, и теперь когда я веду пальцем по экрану, корзина появляется, а когда я заканчиваю вести, то корзина пропадает.. но объект за моим пальцем не следует...(

Comment: НЕТ! Первое условие содержит только одну команду - включение корзины. Только эта строка должна быть в фигурных скобках. Или вообще без них. А потом идет следующее условие через else if.  Т.е. при касании - включаем корзину, при передвижении - двигаем объект, при отпуске касания - убираем корзину.

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: сработало? Или просто полезно? Если сработало - напишу ответ, а комментарии удалю.

Comment: просто полезно((...

Comment: В смысле просто полезно? Вы написали "Понял, спасибо большое". То есть мой метод не работает?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MoveObject()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            _isMoved = true;

            _busketImage.SetActive(true);

            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speed, 
                transform.position.y, 
                transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speed);
        }
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            _isMoved = false;

            _busketImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: во первых спасибо за ответ! но я же написал, что если я пишу destroyObject.Basket.SetActive(true) в скрипте, который отвечает за движение объекта, то объект просто не двигается)